# Binding a v-data-table to a props property in a template

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a vue component which calls a load method returning a multi-part json object. The template of this vue is made up of several sub-vue components where I assign :data="some_object".

This works in all templates except for the one with a v-data-table in that the v-for process (or the building/rendering of the v-data-table) seems to kick-in before the "data" property is loaded.

With an npm dev server if I make a subtle change to the project which triggers a refresh the data-table then loads the data as I expect.

Tried various events to try and assign a local property to the one passed in via "props[]". Interestingly if I do a dummy v-for to iterate through or simply access the data[...] property the subsequent v-data-table loads. But I need to bind in other rules based on columns in the same row and that doesn't work.

Parent/main vue component:

```
...
  <v-flex xs6 class="my-2">
    <ShipViaForm :data="freight"></ShipViaForm>
  </v-flex>
  <OrderHeaderForm :data="orderheader"></OrderHeaderForm>
  <v-flex xs12>
    <DetailsForm :data="orderdet" :onSubmit="submit"></DetailsForm>
  </v-flex>
...
```

So in the above the :data property is assigned from the result below for each sub component.

```
...
  methods: {
    load(id) {
      API.getPickingDetails(id).then((result) => {
        this.picking = result.picking;
        this.freight = this.picking.freight;
        this.orderheader = this.picking.orderheader;
        this.orderdet = this.picking.orderdet;
      });
    },
...
```

DetailsForm.vue

```
    <template lang="html">
    <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          <!-- the next div is a dummy one to force the 'data' property to load before v-data-table -->
          <div v-show="false">
            <div class="hide" v-for='header in headers' v-bind:key='header.product_code'>
              {{ data[0][header.value] }}
            </div>
          </div>
        <v-data-table
          :headers='headers'
          :items='data'
          disable-initial-sort
          hide-actions
        >
          <template slot='items' slot-scope='props'>
            <td v-for='header in headers' v-bind:key='header.product_code'>
              <v-text-field v-if="header.input"
                label=""
                v-bind:type="header.type"
                v-bind:max="props.item[header.max]"
                v-model="props.item[header.value]">
              </v-text-field>
              <span v-else>{{ props.item[header.value] }}</span>
              </td>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
        </v-card-title>
    </v-card>
</template>

<script>
import API from '@/lib/API';

export default {
  props: ['data'],
  data() {
    return {
      valid: false,
      order_id: '',
      headers: [
        { text: 'Order Qty', value: 'ord_qty', input: false },
        { text: 'B/O Qty', value: 'bo_qty', input: false },
        { text: 'EDP Code', value: 'product_code', input: false },
        { text: 'Description', value: 'product_desc', input: false },
        { text: 'Location', value: 'location', input: false },
        { text: 'Pick Qty', value: 'pick_qty', input: true, type: 'number', max: ['ord_qty'] },
        { text: 'UM', value: 'unit_measure', input: false },
        { text: 'Net Price', value: 'net_price', input: false },
      ],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    const { id } = this.$route.params;
    this.order_id = id;
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      if (this.valid) {
        API.updateOrder(this.order_id, this.data).then((result) => {
          console.log(result);
          this.$router.push({
            name: 'Orders',
          });
        });
      }
    },
    clear() {
      this.$refs.form.reset();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this will help someone else who can't see the forest for the trees...

When I declared the data() { ... } properties in the parent form I initialised orderdet as {} instead of [].